# How to treat a file use awk

Tags: shell, awk

I want to read a file using `awk` but I got stuck on fourth field where it automatically breaks after a comma.

Data:- test.txt

```
"A","B","ls","This,is,the,test"
"k","O","mv","This,is,the,2nd test"
"C","J","cd","This,is,the,3rd test"

cat test.txt | awk -F , '{ OFS="|" ;print $2 $3 $4 }'
```

output

```
"B"|"ls"|"This
"O"|"mv"|"This
"J"|"cd"|"This
```

But output should be like this

```
"B"|"ls"|"This,is,the,test"
"O"|"mv"|"This,is,the,2nd test"
"J"|"cd"|"This,is,the,3rd test"
```

Any idea

Comment: awk is not gonna recognise the quotes. you need to either use other tools, or write yourself a customized split function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")' -v OFS='|' '{print $2,$3,$4}' file
"B"|"ls"|"This,is,the,test"
"O"|"mv"|"This,is,the,2nd test"
"J"|"cd"|"This,is,the,3rd test"
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content

With other awks you'd do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="|" }
{
    nf=0
    delete f
    while ( match($0,/([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")/) ) {
        f[++nf] = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print f[2], f[3], f[4]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"B"|"ls"|"This,is,the,test"
"O"|"mv"|"This,is,the,2nd test"
"J"|"cd"|"This,is,the,3rd test"
```

Comment: Thank you...dear...(+1 ) I will delete my answer because readers should opt the best and portable solution... Thanks for teaching me new stuff...happy coding

Comment: Ed Morton, Suppose I'm trying to process this type of line "A","B","ls",,"This,is,the,test" through above method then I'm not print $4.Any idea.

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk`, you can also use:

```
awk -F'\",\"' 'BEGIN{OFS="\"|\""}{print "\""$2,$3,$4}' filename
```

Note: This will only work assuming `","` is not found in between the string. That is it is used as field separator.

Output:

```
"B"|"ls"|"This,is,the,test"
"O"|"mv"|"This,is,the,2nd test"
"J"|"cd"|"This,is,the,3rd test"
```

**OR**

somewhat better:

```
awk -F'^\"|\",\"|\"$' 'BEGIN{OFS="\"|\""}{print "\""$3,$4,$5"\""}' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

In `awk`:

```
awk -F'"' '{for(i=4;i<=9;i+=2) {if(i==4){s="\""$i"\""}else{s = s "|\"" $i"\""}}; print s}' test.txt
```

---

**Explanation**

- `-F'"'` to denote comma separated fields
- awk explanation:

  ```
  {
  ## use for-loop to go over fields
  ## skips the comma field (i.e. increment by +2)
  ## OP wanted to start at field 2, this means the 4th term
  ## OP wanted to end at field 4, this means the 8th term
  for(i=4;i<=8;i+=2) {

      if(i==4){
          ## initialization
          ## use variable s to hold output (i.e. quoted first field $i)
          s="\"" $i "\""
      } else {
          ## for rest of field $i,
          ## prepend '|' and add quotes around $i
          s = s "|\"" $i "\""
      }
  };

  ## print output
  print s 
  }
  ```

Comment: The loop should begin in number `4`, to skip first field, as the OP points out in his question.

Comment: @Birei OP said his code gets stuck at 4 -- and I try to solve this by using `"` (not `,`) as field sep

Comment: I mean your command prints first field, when in the example it seems that he wants to skip it, regardless of the problem with commas.

Comment: csiu@ thanks 4 ur reply,but I want to extract only 2,3 and 4 fields from the file but above code return all the fields from the file.

Comment: @akhileshchand -- oops, wasn't paying attention. I changed to for loop conditions ... what about now?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) much for this kind of task. My suggestion is to use a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) parser, for example, [python](/questions/tagged/python) has a built-in module to handle this. You can use it like:

```
import csv
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    csvwriter = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in csvreader:
        csvwriter.writerow(row[1:])
```

And run it like:

```
python3 script.py infile
```

That yields to `stdout`:

```
"B"|"ls"|"This,is,the,test"
"O"|"mv"|"This,is,the,2nd test"
"J"|"cd"|"This,is,the,3rd test"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/^..../,"")gsub(/","/,"\042""|""\042")}1' file

"B"|"ls"|"This,is,the,test"
"O"|"mv"|"This,is,the,2nd test"
"J"|"cd"|"This,is,the,3rd test"
```