# How to subtract 2 numbers in 2 different files?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have 2 files that are reports of size of the Databases (1 file is from yesterday, 1 from today).
I want to see how the size of each database changed, so I want to calculate the difference.

File looks like this:

```
"DATABASE","Alloc MB","Use MB","Free MB","Temp MB","Hostname"

"EUROPE","9133508","8336089","797419","896120","server3"
"ASIA","3740156","3170088","570068","354000","server5"
"AFRICA","4871331","4101711","769620","318412","server4"
```

Other file is the same, only the numbers are different.

I want to see how the database size changed (so ONLY column **"Use MB"**).

I guess I cannot use "diff" or "awk" options since numbers may change dramatically each day. The only good 'algoritm' I can think of is to subtract numbers between 5th and 6th double quote ("), how do I do that?

Comment: Please do mention logic of getting the difference which column's are responsible for that? Also kindly do mention your efforts in your post too.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this (using `awk`):

```sh
paste file1 file2 -d ',' |awk -F ',' '{gsub(/"/, "", $3); gsub(/"/, "", $9); print $3 - $9}'
```

`paste` puts the two files next to another, separated by a comma (`-d ','`). So you will have :

```
"DATABASE","Alloc MB","Use MB","Free MB","Temp MB","Hostname","DATABASE","Alloc MB","Use MB","Free MB","Temp MB","Hostname"

"EUROPE","9133508","8336089","797419","896120","server3","EUROPE","9133508","8336089","797419","896120","server3"
...
```

`gsub(/"/, "", $3)` removes the quotes around column 3

And finally we print column 3 minus column 9

Comment: I have file1 and file2.  When I run your command, I get:

user@server3:~/temp$ paste file1 file2 -d ',' |awk -F ',' '{gsub(/"/, "", $3); gsub(/"/, "", $9); print $3 - $9}'
paste: cannot open -d
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @korodani that's weird, I don't have that problem at all, what system are you on? Also the quotes around the comma are unecessary, maybe you'll have better luck with `paste file1 file2 -d ,` ?

Comment: I tried without quotes around the comma, I  get the same error output. My system is  SunOS xsnoahd01 5.11 11.3 sun4v sparc sun4v

Comment: Ok, and what does `paste --version` returns for you ?

Comment: paste --version returns me :   paste: illegal option -- version
usage: paste [-s] [-d list] file

Comment: @korodani So i guess we don't have the same paste implementation. From the message, it looks like you might need to do `paste -d , file1 file` insteas

Comment: Thanks Sami, but it's the same. And I cannot install / upgrade any tool on the server because it's a productional environment.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I missed something, but I don't get why you could not use `awk` as it can totally do

> The only good 'algoritm' I can think of is to subtract numbers between
>   5th and 6th double quote ("), how do I do that?

Let's say that file1 is :

```
"DATABASE","Alloc MB","Use MB","Free MB","Temp MB","Hostname"

"EUROPE","9133508","8336089","797419","896120","server3"
"ASIA","3740156","3170088","570068","354000","server5"
"AFRICA","4871331","4101711","769620","318412","server4"
```

And file2 is :

```
"DATABASE","Alloc MB","Use MB","Free MB","Temp MB","Hostname"

"EUROPE","9133508","8335089","797419","896120","server3"
"ASIA","3740156","3170058","570068","354000","server5"
"AFRICA","4871331","4001711","769620","318412","server4"
```

Command

```
awk -F'[",]' 'NR>2&&NR==FNR{db[$2]=$8;next}FNR>2{print $2, db[$2]-$8}' file1 file2
```

gives you result :

```
EUROPE 1000
ASIA 30
AFRICA 100000
```

You can also use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31238219/4289380) to deal more properly with quotechars on awk.

---

If your awk version cannot support multiple field delimiters, you can try this :

```
awk -F, 'NR>2&&NR==FNR{db[$1]=$3;next}FNR>2{print $1, db[$1]-$3}' <(sed 's,",,g' file1) <(sed 's,",,g' file2)
```

Comment: I created file1 and file2 with the content in your example. When I run your Command, I get nothing. No errors in syntax, nor any output :/

Comment: @korodani what does it print when you do `awk -F'[",]' '{print $2, $8}' file1` ?

Comment: it prints 5 empty rows.

Comment: Just FYI, uname -a returns me:
SunOS xsnoahd01 5.11 11.3 sun4v sparc sun4v

Comment: @korodani do you have `nawk` or `gawk` also installed ? You might try to one of these versions.

Comment: @korodani if not, I edited my answer with a code that should work at least on my examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201420/discussion-between-korodani-and-corentin-limier).